# APIM mediation sequence pass through Proxy

Tags: proxy, dns, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am working with **WSO2 APIM manager** in an isolated network environment and I need to access an end point outsite of this network zone: say `https://my.endpoint`. Luckily, there is a proxy (say `http://the.localproxy:8080`). Typically, in curl, I can do this successfully

```sh
curl -X POST https://my.endpoint/datahub/1.0.1/deliveryform_list --proxy http://the.localproxy:8080 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"company_code ": "1040", "offset": "0", "limit": "20", "date_from": "1574469733", "date_to": "1574772672", "search": "","refused" : "0","delivered" : "1","impossible_drain" : "0"}'
```

### axis2.xml

I added the following in `repository/conf/axis2/axis.xml`:

```xml
<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender">
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <!-- HERE -->
        <parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">the.localproxy</parameter>
        <parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">8080</parameter>
        <parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">localhost|.*\.intra$</parameter>
</transportSender>

<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
                <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
        <!-- =======+++++++HERE++++++======= -->
        <parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">the.localproxy</parameter>
        <parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">8080</parameter>
        <parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">localhost|.*\.intra</parameter>
        <parameter name="dynamicSSLProfilesConfig">
            <filePath>repository/resources/security/sslprofiles.xml</filePath>
            <fileReadInterval>600000</fileReadInterval>
        </parameter>
</transportSender>
```

### Problem

However, connections do not seem to reach the external world.

```java
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-12-06 10:41:31,420]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://my.endpoint/datahub/1.0.1/deliveryform_list] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}                                                 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 60000 ms             
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:155)             
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:179)           
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)                                                
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionMan
ager.java:1361)                                                                                                                      
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)                            
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)                               
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)                                               
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:704)                             
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)                                               
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81)                                                       
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459)   
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)                    
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)                                                              
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:441)                                   
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)                            
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)                                                 
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:490)                     
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:382)                            
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:88)                                 
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85)                                                     
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547)                              
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:384)                                             
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.send(HTTPEndpoint.java:85)                                                      
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:164)                               
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:119)                                          
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)                                  
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)                                   
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)                                      
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)                                  
--                                                                                                                                   
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:66)        
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:75)  
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)                                                                         
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)                      
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)                                      
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)                                            
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)                     
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)                              
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)                                                           
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)            
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)                   
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)                                             
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)                                 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)                                           
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                                           
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                                                                                     
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out                                                                        
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)                                                                     
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)                                              
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)                                       
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)                                                
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)                                                                
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)                                                                                  
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)                                                            
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                               
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                             
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                     
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)                                                                          
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)             
        ... 46 more                                                                                                                  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-12-06 10:41:31,427]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with a
ddress https://my.endpoint/datahub/1.0.1/deliveryform_list will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointCon
text}
```

Am I right to assume that i) endpoint access are managed by the **gateway** and that ii) those two classes (`PassThroughHttpSender` and `PassThroughHttpSSLSender`) are the one involved in this process?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can configure proxy is globally. The ESB link you have mentioned talks about proxy services in ESB which is different than proxy servers.

If you explain why you don't want to add proxy configurations in `axis2.xml`, someone might be able to help you with that.

Comment: the thing is: there is no preproduction environment and I wanted to avoid editing conf files directly on the server. That being said, I finally did so (in `PassThroughHttpSender` and `PassThroughHttpSSLSender`) and it seems that the domain in not resolved. I'll edit my question to explain